# Visual Studio not compiling

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to compile my code. If I compile it in Arduino IDE it works, but if I try it in Visual Studio 2019 it fails.

I am trying to use a struct as a parameter.
I have tried pointer and `typedef`, but get the same error

I can compile it in Arduino IDE, but the same code gets this error in VS 2019:

> ```
> Compiling debug version of 'test' for 'ATmega2560 (Mega 2560) (Arduino Mega)'
>
> test.ino: 7:17: error: variable or field 'myFunction' declared void
> Error compiling project sources
> Debug build failed for project 'test'
>
> test.ino: 7:17: error: 'data' was not declared in this scope
> test.ino:7: note  suggested alternative  atan
>    atan
> ```

```cpp
struct data{
    float data;
};

data data_struct;

void myFunction(data data_struct){

}

int main(){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide a declaration for myFunction. That's done by the Arduino IDE behind the scenes.

Try:

```
struct data{
    float data;
};

data data_struct;

void myFunction(data data_struct);
void myFunction(data data_struct){

}

int main(){}
```